# 'nuget pack' fails, unable to load system.collections.immutable, which the assembly doesn't use

Tags: msbuild, nuget, cakebuild

I'm trying to create a NuGet package from an assembly, which is actually a [Cake Build](http://cakebuild.net) addin. It references two NuGet packages itself: `Cake.Core`, and `System.ValueTuple`, with the other additional references being `System` and `System.Core`.

The .nuspec file was created using `nuget spec MyAddin.csproj`, and everything should be good. When I run the `pack` command I get the error "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Collections.Immutable, Version=1.2.1.0, ...".

I've checked both `Cake.Core` and `System.ValueTuple` in dotPeek, and neither of them reference `System.Collections.Immutable`.

I can build the assembly with no problems from the command line. But not the NuGet package. I don't understand what's going on.

Here is the full output:

```
PS C:\path\to\MyAddin> .\tools\nuget.exe pack .\MyAddin\MyAddin.csproj -verbo
sity detailed
NuGet Version: 4.3.0.4406
Attempting to build package from 'MyAddin.csproj'.
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '15.3.409.57025' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017
\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\bin'. Use option -MSBuildVersion to force nuget to use a specific version of MSBuild.
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Collections.Immutable, Version=1.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f
11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Collections.Immutable, Version=1.2.1.0, Culture
=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Collections.Immutable, Version=1.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.LazyItemEvaluator`4.ProcessItemElement(String rootDirectory, ProjectItemElement itemEle
ment, Boolean conditionResult)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.EvaluateItemElement(Boolean itemGroupConditionResult, ProjectItemElement it
emElement, LazyItemEvaluator`4 lazyEvaluator)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.EvaluateItemGroupElement(ProjectItemGroupElement itemGroupElement, LazyItem
Evaluator`4 lazyEvaluator)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.Evaluate(ILoggingService loggingService, BuildEventContext buildEventContex
t)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.Reevaluate(ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, ProjectLoadSettings loa
dSettings)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ReevaluateIfNecessary(ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, ProjectLoadS
ettings loadSettings)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.Initialize(IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion, String subTools
etVersion, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor(String projectFile, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion,
String subToolsetVersion, ProjectCollection projectCollection, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor(String projectFile, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion)

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.

Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

Edit: Adding the `System.Collections.Immutable` v1.3.0 NuGet package, which is actually `System.Collections.Immutable` assembly version 1.2.1, makes no difference

Comment: As a side note, you don't need the dependency on Cake.Core.  Cake itself makes this available, so your addin doesn't need it.

Comment: @GaryEwanPark And if a utility class in the addin should need ```ICakeLog``` or the ```IFileSystem``` abstraction?

Comment: You can do a private reference, that way is only used at design time in Visual Studio.